# Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=(x+3)(x^2-1)$ at the point $(2,15)$.

Tags: calculus

> Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y = (x+3)(x^2-1)$ at the point $(2,15)$, using the Product Rule.

Comment: Well, you'll need the derivative of each component separately, so that's a good place to start.  Once you have that, apply the product rule to get the general derivative: if $f=gh$, then $f' = gh' + hg'$.  Lastly, evaluate that derivative at $x=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the product rule $f'(x)=(x+3)(2x)+(x^2-1)(1)\Rightarrow f'(x)=3x^2+6x-1$

To find slope $m$ of the tangent line at point $(2,15)$, set $x=2$ in $f'(x)$. Thus, $$m\Rightarrow f'(2)=3(2)^2+6(2)-1\Rightarrow m=23$$
Now we have values for $m, y_1, x_1$. Thus the equation shall be:
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-15=23(x-2)$$
$$\therefore y=23x-31$$